# RewriteRule a working URI to a new format

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am formatting the redirect of my site URL using this. I got a problem on redirecting properly.

browser link is like that :

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/1234/user
```

my project need it to be like that :

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/index.php?id=1234&username=user
```

but i don't know how to do that .

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&username=$2
```

sory:

new correction  without / before index.php

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&username=$2 [L]
```

and if your base url is  www.domanin.com/folder1/folder2  then  this line will be:

```
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2
```

Comment: I added your code in .htaccess and restart my httpd but when i request url /1234/user i get 404 not found . should i do any others to get it work ?

Comment: what is your base url?

Comment: sorry you try this. RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&username=$2

Comment: it works with the first answer perfect just i add [L] at the end of line , thank you so much Ahosan